# How to change the orientation of the editor in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Currently, the assistant editor is on the bottom view:
[image: Screen]
I've gone to View > Change Editor Orientation, but it doesn't change anything. It just looks as it did before. I'm working on a 13 inch display if that could be a reason. I would like the display to have the storyboard and assistant editor side by side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`View > Change Editor Orientation` does change something.

Please look at the little icon at the top right side of the editor window.

- By default the assistant editor is opened at the right side [image]
- After selecting `View > Change Editor Orientation` the editor is opened on the bottom [image].

You can change the orientation temporarily by holding the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that, but the assistant editor still appeared on the bottom regardless. What happened to fix the issue was clicking on the double rings in the top right, going to layout, then going to assistant on right.

Comment: Wow, @GabN. You saved my day. After realizing that menu, it makes sense, even though not obvious...

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it helped.